# Sublime Text doesn't compile with Anaconda

Tags: python, sublimetext3, conda

I've just installed Sublime Text, trying to test out this IDE, I'm trying to put this simple line of code in:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
x = range(100)
y = [x**2 for x in x]
plt.plot(x, y)
```

Just to test it out, and I'm getting an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./python3.3/subprocess.py", line 1104, in _execute_child
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_plugin.py", line 1050, in run_
    return self.run(**args)
  File "C:\Users\Or Work\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages\Conda.sublime-package\commands.py", line 526, in run
  File "C:\Users\Or Work\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages\Conda.sublime-package\commands.py", line 489, in __enter__
  File "C:\Users\Or Work\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages\Conda.sublime-package\commands.py", line 473, in conda_version
  File "./python3.3/subprocess.py", line 576, in check_output
  File "./python3.3/subprocess.py", line 819, in __init__
  File "./python3.3/subprocess.py", line 1110, in _execute_child
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Does anybody knows how to fix this?

P.s I am using Anaconda as my python environment

Thanks for helping!

Comment: We're going to need some information on the Conda environment, and how you set up Sublime to work with Conda.

Comment: I've simply used this guide to set it up: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/integration/sublime/ , what kind of information about the conda envrionment? @AMC